# Trying to write a media query on Turbo theme / Shopify in CSS and its not working?

Tags: css, shopify

Very new to code here but trying to sort out some images on a new website and cant seem to get the media query working.

I am using the Turbo theme from out of the sandbox which allows you to enter custom CSS in elements.

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
    .OVDGF-logos { width: 10%; }
}
```

I just used 10% randomly to see a change if it happened but its not making any difference.

Is that media query written correctly? Here is the picture of the element:
[image]

Comment: Try simple `min-width` instead of `min-device-width`?

Comment: thanks for your response! :) I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: if you want to add CSS for mobile devices only use `max-width` instead of `min-width`, `min-width` is like starting point and `max-width` ending point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate CSS file and include it in "theme.liquid" file or respective template.

> ```
> @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
>   .OVDGF-logos{
>     width: 50% !important;
>   }
>  }
> ```

According to their FAQs, The Custom CSS field will only accept CSS. It does not accept SCSS/SASS or media queries and mixins.

Reference: https://help.outofthesandbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022329373-Custom-CSS-Feature-Flex-and-Turbo-Themes